# the structure `request:`

Tags: django

I've seen the line :

```
{% url "requests:applications" as applications_index_url %}
```

I'm familiar with this structure, but not with **`requests:`**. Could anyone be able to explain to me what it means?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It is a [URL namespace](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces), the `url` tag is resolving a view named `applications` in the `requests` namespace

Comment: Could you give me a well understanding instance of a URL namespace?